# Oxidation of Sodium Hydroxide in Ethanol?

Tags: redox, organic-oxidation

So I [read recently](http://www.sciencemadness.org/smwiki/index.php/Sodium_hydroxide) that:

> Alcoholic solutions of sodium hydroxide will oxidize in air, turning brown.

First is this true?

And if so what is oxidizing?

I can't think of what sodium hydroxide would oxidize to, and ethanol well wouldn't that oxidize to water and CO2!

Comment: Alcohol may be oxidized to aldehyde or acid.

Comment: @KemonoChen ah true! But would that turn brown?

Comment: In the presence of alkali (or acid, for that matter) aldehyde will turn against itself, creating all matters of ugly polycondensate products. See [Aldol condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldol_condensation) and note that it ends up in another aldehyde, so the process can and will be repeated.

Comment: Maybe the solution forms sodium alkoxide  which is a solid that gradually turns dark in dry air due to oxidation. In moist air, it hydrolyze rapidly to sodium hydroxide. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_ethoxide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Answer based on comments from @KemonoChen, @IvanNeretin and @NilayGhosh. Thanks for your input :D]

> In the presence of alkali (or acid, for that matter) aldehyde will
>   turn against itself, creating all matters of ugly polycondensate
>   products. See [Aldol
>   condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldol_condensation) and
>   note that it ends up in another aldehyde, so the process can and will
>   be repeated

So yes it can happen.

And is is most likely ethanol oxidation to an aldehyde, which has (aldol) condensed into an 'ugly polycondensate'

It may also be Sodium Alkoxide, which is known to turn brown.